# How to simulate a loaded dice in R

Tags: r, statistics, simulation

Consider a loaded dice such that the probability to obtain an outcome of 1 is 2p/3, the probability of obtaining 2, 3, 4 or 5 is p each, and the probability of obtaining 6 is 3p/2.

1. Create a computer program to simulate the above loaded dice. Generate output.
2. Use the output to make a plot to check that your program works correctly.

I found p to be 6/37 but I do not know how to code for a loaded dice.

I know how to simulate a fair dice:

```
sample(1:6, size=1, replace = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to do this: you can set the probabilities inside sample by specifying the `prob` argument.

Also note that I set a random seed with `set.seed`: this allows to make your results reproducible.

```
p <- 6/37
myprobs <- c(2/3 * p, p, p, p, p, 3/2*p)

set.seed(1)
x <- sample(1:6, size = 100, replace = TRUE, prob = myprobs)

barplot(table(x))
```

[image]